# working example of tweet with image using javascript django

Tags: javascript, django, twitter

I am trying to tweet with image using javascript.I read about cards, and put the following on page i am sharing:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="http://203.110.93.244/">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - The guest list and parade of limousines witproject here.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.promon.in/media/images/products/2015/09/listing_image_vsRFOqw.jpg">
```

then i use this javascript to tweet:

```
twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
        'http://203.110.93.244/offers/eat-n-drink/Delhi-greater-kailash-rara-avis/81/',
        document.getElementById('twitter-btn'),
        {
            text: '#HelloWorld',
        });
```

Problem is, I am not getting any image thumbnail.
Please guide me towards a viable solution.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to apply for twitter cards on twitters api page

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as follows works for me. It opens a window whenever the user clicks a button... It sends the "URL" of the source page, "via" which is your twitter username, and "text" which is whatever message you want to appear in there. Note that the amount of text is limited and if too long Twitter silently eliminate part of the data.

The page URL with the image must appear first. You can test the validity of the page here: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

```
jQuery("#twitter-share-button").click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var uri = "http://203.110.93.244/offers/eat-n-drink/Delhi-greater-kailash-rara-avis/81/";
    var tweet = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url="
          + encodeURI(uri)
          + "&via=yourtwittername&text="
          + encodeURI(uri)
          + encodeURI(" #your-hash-tag ")
          + encodeURI("some more text here");
    window.open(tweet, "Share on Twitter");
  });
```