# How do I tweet out my image like I do when I share with facebook?

Tags: php, twitter

I managed to find a way with facebook, but no so much with Twitter. The only progress I got is only with text, but I want it with my image that I shared.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<a href='uploads/".$row['image']."' data-caption='".$row['text']."'> ";
        echo "<img  id='img_div'  src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/>";
        //echo "<p id='img_div'>".$row['desc']."</p>";
        echo "</a>";
        echo"<p id='p_div'>Share</p>";
        echo "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.example.com/uploads/".$row['image']."'>
        <i id='share_div' class='fa fa-facebook fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
        echo "<a id='tweet_div' href='http://www.twitter.com/share?text=Check out this image from &quot;Quotin&quot;!&url=http://www.eample.com/uploads/".$row['image']."'&via=_Quotin_'>Tweet</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Comment: I know about this, but what is the code for it?

Comment: It's in the meta tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter - share button, but with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825195/twitter-share-button-but-with-image)